# Test equality of/filter geometries in sf?

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial, purrr, r-sf

Might be missing something here, but didn't find anything after a bunch of digging. I am attempting to find rows of `sf` objects where the geometry takes a certain value. This is for tidying purposes where the same geometry may have been stored with different associated metadata (such as id and other values) in different datasets, and I need to resolve discrepancies.

Normally it is easy to filter for certain values using `dplyr` like so:

Load required packages

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
#> Loading tidyverse: tibble
#> Loading tidyverse: tidyr
#> Loading tidyverse: readr
#> Loading tidyverse: purrr
#> Loading tidyverse: dplyr
#> Conflicts with tidy packages ----------------------------------------------
#> filter(): dplyr, stats
#> lag():    dplyr, stats
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.0, proj.4 4.9.3
```

Load example dataset

```r
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source `C:\Users\Calum You\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\sf\shape\nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
```

As expected, `dplyr::filter` works well on different columns. We can easily choose the row with `NAME` Ashe and `CNTY_ID` 1825, which is the first row:

```r
nc %>% filter(NAME == "Ashe")
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.23436 xmax: -81.23989 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
#>    AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
#> 1 0.114     1.442  1825    1825 Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#>   NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                       geometry
#> 1      10  1364     0      19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.4727554...
nc %>% filter(CNTY_ID == 1825)
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.23436 xmax: -81.23989 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
#>    AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
#> 1 0.114     1.442  1825    1825 Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#>   NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                       geometry
#> 1      10  1364     0      19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.4727554...
```

Does not work well when attempting to filter on the geometry column. I would hope that this returned only the first row of `nc`, since that is the row of `nc` where `geometry` is equal to (by definition) the first geometry `nc$geometry[1]'.

```r
nc %>% filter(geometry == nc$geometry[1])
#> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo): Evaluation error: operation == not supported.
nc %>% filter(geometry == st_geometry(nc)[1])
#> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo): Evaluation error: operation == not supported.
```

The error message suggests that even the `==` operator does not work:

```r
nc$geometry[1] == nc$geometry[1]
#> Error in Ops.sfc(nc$geometry[1], nc$geometry[1]): operation == not supported
```

`identical()` works, but not for the purposes of constructing my own filter. Would want to see `TRUE` for the first element of the output, but I don't think `identical()` works like that in the map functions.

```r
identical(nc$geom[1], nc$geom[1])
#> [1] TRUE
map_lgl(nc$geometry, function(x) identical(x, nc$geometry[1]))
#>   [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [12] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [34] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [45] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [56] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [67] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [78] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [89] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [100] FALSE
```

Is `==` simply not defined for geometries in `sf`? If so, are there alternatives for testing equality or otherwise finding geometries that are the same in different datasets? I am near to resorting to `rbind` different datasets together and use `duplicated()` to do this, but that would require ensuring that all columns in both are the same and seems like unexpected/needless hassle.

Thanks for making it to the end of the question - any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: `nc2 <- rbind(nc, nc); map_lgl(nc2$geometry, ~ identical(., nc2$geometry[[1]])) # work; nc2 %>% filter(map_lgl(nc2$geometry, ~ identical(., nc2$geometry[[1]]))) # work; nc2 %>% filter(map_lgl(geometry, ~ identical(., geometry[[1]]))) # not work`. It's a bit strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `==` is indeed not defined for sf objects. However, `identical()` works for this purpose if you remember to drill down in the subsetting, as noted by [cuttlefish44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149388/test-equality-of-filter-geometries-in-sf#comment81249569_47149388). This, for example, works fine:

```
identical(nc$geom[[1]], nc$geom[[1]])
map_lgl(nc$geometry, function(x) identical(x, nc$geometry[[1]]))
  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [22] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [43] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [64] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [85] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I suppose this is to do with confusion on my part about how `sf` stores geometries: the `sfg` is not actually a list but contains the list of points for the geometry. Glad to have figured a workaround, regardless.

EDIT: I did not realise that `st_equals` is implemented in `sf`. It has a different syntax but is probably the best tool for this purpose, since it describes area equality rather than data structure equality.